# How to find the git repo of a mvn dependency

Tags: git, maven, security

For security reasons I would like to scan the git repo of all dependencies I'm including in my Java/Kotlin projects. Problem is that I don't see a way to automatically find the git repo of the mvn dependencies I'm using.

For npm/yarn I see the git repo in the meta info and so that is easy to do but mvn does not give that info. And might not always be available either...

Is there an automated way to get the source repo for my mvn dependencies?

MAG,
Milo

Comment: There is no 100% certain way of getting this information automatically.  Maven predates git with at least a decade.

Comment: Note that most modern artifacts have sources attached which you can use with a search engine

Answer (score 1):

You have to look at the provided pom.xml file. The Maven pon.xml can contain XML elements that specify the SCM "connection" (thus the repository location).

Take for example the POM of apache commons lang3:
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.14.0/commons-lang3-3.14.0.pom

It contains the following block:

```
<scm>
<connection>scm:git:http://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf/commons-lang.git</connection>
<developerConnection>scm:git:https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf/commons-lang.git</developerConnection>
<url>https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf?p=commons-lang.git</url>
<tag>rel/commons-lang-3.13.0</tag>
</scm>
```

Of course not all artifacts in Maven have such a section. But those that have it you can easily extract the git location from. And for other projects you encounter often you can open an issue and ask them to include this section in their pom.xml of future versions that are published to a public Maven repo.